# How to split a line of text separated by "," into a file containing one string per line?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file containing strings in the format of `A,B,C,D...`, and I would like to save them into a file by using standard Linux utilities  as:

```
A
B
C
D 
...
```

The content in the original file is dynamic, which could contain 0, 1, 2, or more strings. How do I do that?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) see also [How do I ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

Use `tr` to change all the commas into newlines:

```
$ cat input.txt 
a,b,c
d,e
f
$ tr , '\n' < input.txt 
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to find contiguous strings of non-comma characters, the new lines come for “free”.

```
grep -Eo "[^,]+" input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat > file
a,b,c
d,e
f
perl -pe "s/,/\n/g" file
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -pe 's:g/\,/\n/;'
```

OR (perhaps more readable):

```
raku -pe 's:g[\,] = qq[\n];'
```

Sample Input:

```
a,b,c
d,e
f
```

Sample Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Note: using either the first `s///` or the second `s[…]=[…]` form, you can change the `/` or `[]` delimiter/delimiter-pairs to another character/characters (e.g. using `s{…}={…}` instead), should you encounter difficulties in quoting/escaping your input text.

https://raku.org